# Integrating Angular 5 App and Spring boot. Spring security blocks the app

Tags: spring, angular, spring-boot, spring-security

I have added the built angular app to the static folder under resources. when i go to `localhost:8080`, the app is not shown. How do i configure spring security to allow only the angular 5 app through.

My Http configuration:

```
http
            .cors()
                .and()
            .csrf()
                .disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                .and()
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/users/checkUsernameAvailability",
                        "/users/checkEmailAvailability")
                    .permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
```

Comment: What response do you get? Any error message or HTTP status?  What is the message in your log?

Comment: @dur i get the 401 Not Authenticated Message

Answer (score 0):

You have following:

```
.anyRequest().authenticated();
```

So accessing `http://localhost:8080` which is the root will be blocked by Spring Security if you are not logged in.

Try logging in adding following line.

```
.antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
```

The above line must be only for testing.